# Recommend versioning software for Visual Studio 2010 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can anyone recommend good versioning software for Visual Studio 2010 Pro, preferably free and easy to setup.

I use Windows 7 btw if that matters.

Comment: Similar question. A bit old, but still relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372687/good-visual-studio-svn-tool

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) has good integration with Visual Studio and TortoiseSVN. I like it more than AnkhSVN. The single problem with VisualSVN - it's not free

Comment: Do I need an external server, or can I do it on my Windows 7 OS that I use?

Comment: yes, you need SVN server. You can use it locally or setup remote one. There's also VisualSVNServer product on this link

Comment: @AndyT It seems situation is changing: VisualSVN 3.0 will be free when used on computer that are not joined to Active Directory domain: http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/pre-release/

Answer (score 1):

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is definitely my favorite. It's a free SVN plug-in and it's really easy to use.

Comment: Let me add another endorsement for AnkhSVN -- it works well and integrates very nicely with Visual Studio. The only shortcoming (if you can call it that) is that SVN is *not* a distributed VCS. Depending on your situation, a DVCS may fit your needs better.

Comment: There's just me on my laptop.  I want this type of software so I can revert back to a version of a web application that might have been released previously.

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek: if all development is on one machine, then SVN should work nicely, and AnkhSVN is almost certainly the nicest way to use it from VS.

Comment: do you have an SVN server anywhere? its possible to set one up on your own computer using xampp i'd imagine. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: No SVN server installed yet on my laptop.

Comment: zip files with dates then? you will need an external "server" to do file versioning.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about source control? There are many different options for source control, depending on your goals and budget. TFS works best with Visual Studio 2010 and does much more than just source control, but it's not free. For free options subversion (SVN) seems to be quite popular. I used Perforce at my last job and quite liked it, but it's only free for up to 2 users or for OSS development.

Answer (score 0):

If you know [git](http://git-scm.com/), [GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) integrates a plugin in Visual Studio 2010. After installation and configuration of your code repository, you can commit, switch branches, or see the history of your changes, all inside Visual Studio.